# What does Reponse represent in Promise<Reponse> in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, fetch

I'm learning about the fetch method in Javascript and I when I say

`fetch.("url").then(r => {if(r.status!==200)doSomething();} )`

and when I hover over "fetch" it says that it returns `Promise<Response>`, and the r parameter in the function in "then" is a Response.

My question is: what does the type in <> mean? I know that in C++ it represents a template, in this case a class, but how does the function know that the "r" parameter is a Response?

Comment: I think you're asking about Typescript, not JavaScript.

Comment: It is JavaScirpt

Comment: Here's a link to the documentation : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response

Comment: It's an object. Read more here
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response

Comment: Also knowing about what promises are may be useful for comprehension, read the documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What does Reponse represent in Promise in Javascript?

Nothing. `Promise<Response>` is not valid Javascript syntax so it does not mean anything.

> When I hover over "fetch" it says that it returns Promise, and the r parameter in the function in "then" is a Response... My question is: what does the type in <> mean?

The javascript programming language itself does not come with an editor or IDE. Most people write javascript in their favorite text editor. You will need to look at the documentation of your code editor or IDE to know what the popup means.

However we can guess what it means. `<>` is not valid javascript syntax so the programmer who developed the code editor probably took inspiration from C++/Java. My guess is it means the same thing in C++/Java - that being that the Promise is a template/generic (it is not really in javascript since there is no such thing) if you look at it from a C++/Java programmer's point of view and it will compile to an object who's `.then()` method expects a function who's argument is of the type in `<>` (similar to Futures in C++ and Java).

> How does the function know that the "r" parameter is a Response?

It does not. The programmer who wrote the Promise interface expect you to pass a function who accepts one argument to its `.then()` method. The programmer's code will then **call** the function you pass to `.then()` and pass it the **`Response`** object.

Here's an example. Let me write this simple function:

```
function sayHello (formatter) {
    console.log(formatter("Hello World"));
}
```

Now let's use the function above:

```
sayHello(h => {
    return "This is a " + h.toUpperCase() + " program";
})
// output = This is a HELLO WORLD program
```

Your question is how does the `sayHello` function know that the `h` parameter is a string who's value is "Hello World"?

The answer is simple, It's because **I, the programmer** who wrote the `sayHello()` function, pass it to you.

How would **you** know that `h` is the string "Hello World"? Well, hopefully I would have written some documentation somewhere for you to read.

So how would you know what is the value of `r` in your code? You need to read the documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch. Specifically the first sentence in the second paragraph:

> The promise resolves to the Response object representing the response to your request.

Comment: "*the programmer who developed the code editor probably took inspiration from C++/Java*" or most likely from TypeScript which 1. already does have the same syntax (well, influenced by Java/C++/C#) and 2. Already documents native JS types and functions.

Answer (score 1):

Your IDE helped you infer that the response type of the `fetch` function is `Promise<Response>`, and `<>` is the way of passing generic types of TypeScript. For the type of `Response`, please refer to https: //developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response

In fact this is just a way for the IDE to assist in writing JavaScript. If you want strict type checking, please use TypeScript.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Mark C., The fetch method returns a Promise of type [Response](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response).

When you hover over the method in your IDE, your IDE uses TypeScript internally to infer the types of the return type and arguments of this method.